# How to extend the default behaviour of a prop of a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

Hello I have table component taken from ant design's table and I want to change what happens when you change your current page.

```
function DefaultTable<T extends Entity>(props: TableProps<T>): JSX.Element {
const { pagination } = props;
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [currentPageSize, setCurrentPageSize] = useState<number>();
return (
  <Form>
    <Table
      {...props}
      pagination={
        pagination !== false && {
          onChange: e => setCurrentPage(e),
          defaultCurrent: currentPage,
          onShowSizeChange: (_current, newSize) => setCurrentPageSize(newSize),
          pageSize: currentPageSize,
          ...pagination
        }
      }
    />
  </Form>
  );
}
```

However, when I change the page, the filters, sorters and some other configurations are also gone. I think it is because of this onChange function `onChange: e => setCurrentPage(e)`, the default behaviour is ignored. Is there a way to extend the default onChange, and then add my current `setCurrentPage(e)` to it?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking on `Table` and `Pagination` implementation on antd and there is no evidence which explains why adding `onChange` would prevent the default behavior.

https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-filter-panel-antd4123-forked-1nwro?file=/index.js

I also have been playing around the `Table` example provided by antd docs, where I add a `onChange` handle and the filtering behavior remains the same.

Try to isolate the code and provide more info - this way we could help you better.